# If there's no function/variable eldoc shouts void-function

Tags: eldoc

When editing code and the caret moves away from any variable or function, i.e. it's on a blank line the eldoc keeps shouting on the mini buffer

`eldoc-error (void-function t)`

Look at the image that shows the behaviour, the caret sits at line 26 (and for some reason it doesn't showed up on the image)

[image]

How can I configure it so it won't tell me anything whenever I'm not hovering over something with the caret? Ah, and there's one more thing, it is enabled EVERYWHERE, even on dried. I don't know why as I didn't tell him to do so. Even when there's some action on the mini buffer it keeps shouting the same error.

If anyone wants to see my configuration files, come [here](https://github.com/rafaelcn/dotfiles).

Comment: Do you see the same thing with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. Post a step-by-step recipe from `emacs -Q` to repro the problem.

Comment: Does it happen also when using eglot? (If you're on Emacs 29, and gopls is in your path, then just stop LSP and start eglot. As you are not using go-eldoc, I guess eldoc functionality comes from LSP, just guessing...)